# assigning variable score1 & score2 to another variable respectively before resetting them to 0

Tags: c, variables, variable-assignment, assign

so i'm trying to do a badminton scorekeeper.
and having a problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int scorekeeper();
char home[21]="HOME",away[21]="AWAY",choice3;
void scoreboard();
int score1=0,score2=0,set1=0,set2=0,m=1;
int main()
{
    int choice1,choice2,setnum;
    char buf[50];


    printf("\t\t\t/////////////////////////////////\n\t\t\t/     BADMINTON SCOREKEEPER\t/\n\t\t\t/////////////////////////////////\n\n");

    do {
        printf("Do you want to enter players' or teams' names?\n1-Yes\n2-No\n:>>");
        scanf("%d",&choice1);
        switch(choice1) {
        case 1: {
            do {
                printf("\nPlease enter HOME player's or team's name(max 20 characters including space)\n:>>");
                fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
                scanf(" %20[^\n]",&home);
                printf("\nPlease enter AWAY player's or team's name(max 20 characters including space)\n:>>");
                fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
                scanf(" %20[^\n]",&away);
                do {
                    printf("\n\n%.20s VS %.20s\n\n1.Confirm\n2.Edit\n:>>",home,away);
                    fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
                    scanf(" %d",&choice2);
                    if(choice2!=1&&choice2!=2)
                        printf("\n***ERROR. INVALID INPUT***\n\n");
                } while(choice2!=1&&choice2!=2);

            } while(choice2==2);
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            printf("\nSet up to default:\n%s VS %s\n\n",home,away);
            break;
        }
        default: {
            printf("\n***ERROR. INVALID SELECTION***\n\n");
            break;
        }
        }
    } while(choice1!=1&&choice1!=2);
    do {
        printf("\n\nHow many sets you want to play?\n(enter 1,3 or 5)\n:>>");
        scanf("%d",&setnum);
        if(setnum!=1&&setnum!=3&&setnum!=5)
            printf("\n\n***INVALID INPUT. PLEASE RE-ENTER***\n\n");
    } while(setnum!=1&&setnum!=3&&setnum!=5);

    printf("\n\nSTART THE MATCH\n===============\n\n");
    while(setnum>0) {
        --setnum;
        score1=0;
        score2=0;

        while(score1<21&&score2<21) {

            scoreboard();
            scorekeeper();

        }
        if (score1==21&&score2==20||score1==20&&score2==21)
            while(score1!=score2+2&&score2!=score1+2) {
                scoreboard();
                scorekeeper();
                if(score1==29&&score2==29)
                    break;
            }
        if(score1==29&&score2==29) {
            scoreboard();
            scorekeeper();
        }
        if(score1>score2)
            ++set1;
        else
            ++set2;
        scoreboard();
        ++m;
        printf("\n\nEND OF SET\n\n");
        if(set1==set2+2||set2==set1+2)
            break;
    }
    return 0;

}
void scoreboard()
{
    int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j;//here comes the problem
    if(m==1) {
        a=score1;
        b=score2;
        printf("\n\n\t\t       S\n----------------------------\n|%-20s|%2d|%2d|\n----------------------------\n|%-20s|%2d|%2d|\n----------------------------\n\n",home,set1,a,away,set2,b);
    } else if(m==2) {
        c=score1;
        d=score2;
        printf("\n\n\t\t       S\n-------------------------------\n|%-20s|%2d|%2d|%2d|\n-------------------------------\n|%-20s|%2d|%2d|%2d|\n-------------------------------\n\n",home,set1,a,c,away,set2,b,d);

    } else if(m==3) {
        e=score1;
        f=score2;
        printf("\n\n\t\t       S\n-------------------------------\n|%-20s|%2d|%2d|%2d|\n-------------------------------\n|%-20s|%2d|%2d|%2d|\n-------------------------------\n\n",home,set1,a,c,e,away,set2,b,d,f);

    }
    return;
}

int scorekeeper()
{
    printf("\n\nHOT KEYS LIST:\nA-%s SCORES\nL-%s SCORES\n\n",home,away);
    scanf(" %c",&choice3);
    switch(choice3) {
    case 'A':
    case 'a': {
        ++score1;
        break;
    }
    case 'L':
    case 'l': {
        ++score2;
        break;
    }
    default: {
        printf("\n\n***ERROR. INVALID INPUT***\n\n");
        break;
    }
    }
    return score1,score2;
}
```

what i am trying to do is when in set 1, the program will assign value of score1 & score2 to a&b respectively. then going to next set, it'll overwrite value of score1& score2 back to 0 before assigning them to c&d. how am i suppose to do this without affecting value stored in a&b?

Comment: Quickest solution is to change `int a, b, c ...` to `static int a, b, c ...`.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths it works. thanks. but now i have another problem.. if user set to play 3 sets and they're in tie after 2 sets, the output will be like this : http://s9.postimg.org/ajc06qu1b/prob_bdmnton.png is it because of usage of static int or my other parts of coding?

Comment: it's ok. got it where's my problem is.